# Page break just after page header

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I need to export a pdf where the content in Column header / Detail appears on a new page.

```
Page 1 : Title + Page Header
Page 2 : Title + Column header + Detail
Page 3 : Title + Column header + Detail
```

Looking everywhere in forums/documentation, I can't find a way to add a page break after Page Header using *iReport Designer 5.1.0*.

Adding a page break with drag and drop at the bottom of page header with `$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1` juste does nothing.

I'm wondering if it's even possible.

Comment: I think you should invert 'Title' with 'Page Header'. In fact the Title band will be printed only once, at the very beginning of the output file. While Page Header is printed on top of each page in the pdf, there is no page-break or any other way to modify this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name already suggests, "Page Header" is a header on every "Page".
If you want the contents not to be there shift them to title and delete the Page Header.

Also you might want to increase the "Title" height to match the available space on the page so nothing else gets printed on the first page.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help.
You'r both right about inverting Title with Page Header. My main problem though is to have a page break just before Column Header. I don't want anything from Column header/Detail on the first page. A page break on Page Header doesn't seem to work (I still have Column header + Detail on the first page).

Comment: @user2545297 make the Title height match the page height and nothing else will be printed there :)

Comment: I couldn't make the title height match the page height. Moving everything to title and adding a page break with print expression $V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 did the work though. I've got my title,page break, then my content.

Comment: * Page break is alone in page header with $V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1

Comment: @Niallith Creative approach :)